# Creating/filtering fileset from a list in a file or from a property with ant

Tags: java, ant

Let us suppose I have a file called "list-of-files.txt" with this content:

```
file1.txt
file2.properties
file3.class
```

I would like to use this content in a ant :

```
<fileset filelist="list-of-files.txt" />
```

Is it possible?

Also, if I had this list of files in a property:

```
<property name="various.files" value="file1.txt,file2.properties,file3.class" />
```

is there a way to create a fileset with it? Something like:

```
<fileset files="${various.files}" />
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you post details of your solution?

Comment: Hi, emeraldjava. I hope the code at http://pastebin.com/Xhjs43mF can make it more understandable. If it does not help you, ask again! HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [`PatternSet`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/patternset.html)s might be of help. Look at the `includes` and `includesfile` attributes and nested elements. You can also look at the [`FileSet`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) documentation to see how they're used in that context.